# Testing a Django url that has capture groups

Tags: python, django

I have a Django url pattern like so:

```
url(r'browse/state/(?P<state>\d+)$', browse_state_sites)
```

Writing a a test like so results in a State matching query Error.

```
def test_browse_state_county_sites(self):
    resp = self.client.get('/browse/state/1')
    self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
```

How do you pass in capture groups to test a path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give your url a `name` like so:

```
url(r'browse/state/(?P<state>\d+)$', browse_state_sites, name='state-detail')
```

And then in your test code use `django.core.urlresolvers.reverse` like so:

```
resp = self.client.get(reverse('state-detail', kwargs={
  'state': 12345,
}))
```

You might be receiving an error `GET`ing `/browse/state/1/county/1` because, from what you've provided, there is no match for it. The `browse/state/(?P<state>\d+)$` regex will match any url of form `browse/state/<number>` - the `/county/1` will cause match failure.

Comment: Great answer.  Slight syntax error.  Reverse is missing the closing )

Comment: Yeah, sorry - seems to have got eaten by my clipboard when copying from text editor :P